# Utilizar valores de um dataframe no ifelse

Tags: r, data.frame

Tenho o seguinte cenário:

**Data frame - Recursos:**

```
recursos <- as.data.frame(c("server01","server02","server03"));  
colnames(recursos) <- "Server"
```

**Data frame - Eventos:**

```
eventos <- as.data.frame(c("falha no server01","erro no server01","falha no server02","erro no server03"));  
colnames(eventos) <- "Eventos";  
eventos <- dplyr::mutate(eventos, Server = "")
```

Meu objeto é popular a coluna Server no data frame eventos, utilizando como base os servidores mapeados no data frame Recurso. Na solução abaixo, eu consigo preencher utilizando um valor único. Porém não é o que preciso ainda.

```
eventos$Server <- ifelse(grepl("server01", eventos$Eventos), "server01", "")
```

Pensei em rodar um for(servidor in recursos$Server), alterando no grep, por uma variavel. Mas não consegui desta forma. Alguém poderia me ajudar ?

Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atualizando a solução:

```
procura <- as.data.frame(sapply(as.character(recursos$Server), function(x) grepl(x, eventos$Eventos)), stringsAsFactors = F)

# Adiciona uma coluna "Missing" para os casos que não tem nenhum `recurso`
procura$Missing <- F
procura$Missing[rowSums(procura)==0] <- T

for(i in 1:nrow(eventos)) {
  eventos$Server[i] <- colnames(procura)[which(procura[i,]==T)]
}
```

Isso vai funcionar independente do número de servers na base `recursos$Server`

Comment: TheBiro obrigado pela ajuda. O único problema é justamente esse, sua solução atende perfeitamente o meu exemplo. Mas no meu cenário real, são em torno de 200 servidores. Existe uma maneira de incluir um for na sua solução ?

Comment: Entendi, vou reescrever a solução então. Posso assumir que a base `recursos` contém todos os servidores únicos necessários?

Comment: Sim TheBiro, isso mesmo. Imagine que a recursos$Server, possui 200 linhas com 200 servidores diferentes. Nomes aleatórios.

Comment: Basicamente, em cada linha do eventos$Eventos, eu vou na coluna recursos$Server, e vejo se esta contido um dos 200 servidores nesta linha. Se estiver eu preencho a coluna eventos$Server com o nome do servidor identificado.

Comment: Atualizei, faça os testes... se `recursos$Server` possuir as entradas corretas, vai funcionar

Comment: TheBiro,  retornou um erro Error in eventos$Server[i] <- colnames(procura)[which(procura[i, ] == T)] : 
  replacement has length zero

Comment: Estranho, rodei no seu exemplo sem nenhum erro

Comment: A diferença é que no dataframe eventos, inclui os eventos reais que acontecem no meu ambiente. Uma lista com 200 strings diversas "falha no servidor", "erro no servidor","alto consumo no servidor". E no dataframe recursos, ampliei a lista com todos os servidores que possuo.

Comment: Mas para funcionar é necessário que os acontecimentos em `eventos` contem as strings de `recursos` exatamente iguais

Comment: Sim, e são. Um exemplo real: eventos[3,] - > "THE MEMORY HEALTH OF HOST D715WS074 IS NOT OK". recurso[7,] -:> "D715WS074"

Comment: Acho que oq está acontecendo, é que tem valores de `recurso` que não existem em `eventos`, mas é fácil arrumar... Vou atualizar novamente

Comment: TheBiro, com certeza isso pode ocorrer. Na minha base de servidores, consta todos os servidores que possuo. E nem todos geram eventos.

Comment: Tá bem feio mas agora acho que vai!

Comment: TheBiro você é o cara meu amigo. Funcionou perfeitamente !!! Muito Obrigado !!!

Answer (score 1):

Se os eventos contém a informação correta sobre os servidores, como no exemplo fornecido, basta utilizar a função `regmatches` em conjunto com a expressão regular pertinente para extrair as substrings de interesse.

```
eventos <- dplyr::mutate(eventos, Server = regmatches(Eventos, regexpr('server[0-9]+', Eventos)))
```

Apesar de custoso do ponto de vista computacional, podes comparar as palavras em cada mensagem da variável `Eventos` com a lista presente em `Server`

Em uma linha:

```
eventos <- dplyr::mutate(eventos,
                         Server = unlist(lapply(
                         strsplit(as.character(eventos$Eventos), '\\s'),
                         function(x) x[which(x %in% recursos$Server)])))
```

Pressupondo, é claro, que os nomes dos servidores em `Eventos` são sempre iguais e únicos em cada entrada.

Comment: Erikson, eu poderia substituir a expressão regular por uma coluna com vários servidores ? Pergunto isso pois o nome dos meus servidores, são aleatórios, alguns começam com s, outros com x, outros com d. São diversos nomes de servidores. Todos estão na recursos$Servers.

Comment: Vitor, se o último nome na coluna eventos for o nome do servidor pode utilizar esta solução adaptada da solução do Erikson `dplyr::mutate(eventos, Server = regmatches(Eventos, regexpr('\\w+$', Eventos)))`

Comment: Observe que nenhuma das soluções está sendo analizado se o servidor pertence aos `recursos`. Isso poderia te custar mais processamento caso não seja necessário.

Comment: Daniel, o problema é que tenho 200 nomes diferentes de servidores. Alguns começando com X, outros com Y, outros com B. Por isso armazenei a lista global de servidores no dataframe recursos, coluna Servers. A solução do Erikson é muito boa. Vou armazenar esse código para futuras necessidades. Mas para o meu cenário, só falta eu utilizar esta lista de servidores no regmatches.

Comment: Infelizmente, só é possível utilizar uma expressão regular neste caso. Minha sugestão seria criar uma expressão regular mais genérica, que abarque todos os casos, ou utilizar a função `strsplit` para comparar os termos com a lista no `data.frame`. Vou alterar a resposta para acrescentar essa sugestão.

Comment: Erikson, supondo que um dos exemplos nos dataframes sejam estes: eventos[3,] - > "THE MEMORY HEALTH OF HOST D715WS074 IS NOT OK". recursos[7,] -:> "D715WS074". Precisa alterar alguma coisa no seu código ?

Comment: Não precisa alterar nada. Se houver a possibilidade dos `Eventos` não estarem nos `recursos`, é preciso prever um caso padrão.